# Как реализовать перезапуск цикла, пока не будет получено одно из требуемых значений

Tags: python, циклы, исключения

```
nominal = input(int(тут надо ввести значение 2, либо 5, либо 25))
while nominal #не будет равняться 2 or 5 or 25:
   #предлагает снова ввести значение, пока не получит 2, 5, 25
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше это
реализовать, мои попытки привели либо к
ошибкам, либо к несрабатыванию (пропуску)
цикла
Я начинающий питонист, по этому пожалуйста,
обьясните проще

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```py
nominal=0

while not any([nominal==5, nominal==15, nominal==25]):
    nominal=int(input('Введите новое значение:'))
```

Или так:

```
nominal=0
while not (nominal==5 or nominal==15 or nominal==25):
    nominal=int(input('Введите новое значение:'))
```

Ну или так

```py
while True:
   nominal=int(input('Введите новое значение:'))
   if nominal==5 or nominal==15 or nominal==25:
       break
```

Comment: Спасибо, последний вариант помог, все заработало

Comment: Условие можно короче написать: `if nominal in (5, 15, 25):`

Answer (score 0):

```
def input_y(y=(5, 15, 25), t='Введите новое значение:'):
    x = int(input(t))
    return x if x in y else check(y, t)

print(input_y())
```